# How to make a template class that force it's child class to extends itself?

Tags: c++

I would like to know the C++ equivalent of the following Java code.

```
public Class MyClass <T extends MyClass<T>> {...}
```

I have tried the following but failed using C11:

```
template <class T> class Parent {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Parent<T>, T>::value);
public:
    T* next;
};

class Child: public Parent<Child> {
public:
    Child* next;
};
```

Which results in:

```
incomplete type `Child` used in type trait expressions
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] as required here please.

Comment: what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? I have a hard time to understand the title. force a derived class to inherit from its base? You dont need to "force" anything. Once Child inherits from Parent it does already inherit from Parent. I suppose you actually want to ask "How to require a template type argument of Parent to derive from Parent?"

Comment: btw I suggest to not try too hard to see parallels between Java generics and C++ templates, under the hood they are rather different concepts (and also not under the hood)

Comment: This is known as the CRTP (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern) and is widely used. The `next` member is not necessary, btw. you can static cast Parent up to Child.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number sorry to be unclear on the topic...
What I am trying to do is to create a template linked list nodes so that other classes can inherits. But the problem is I dont want the ```next``` variable to have the type of the super class but the child class itself. Just wondering if there is a way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, within [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), `T` is an incomplete type (so most traits won't work on it).

You might add the check in a member instead (type would be complete at that point).

Good candidates are constructor and destructor:

```
template <class T>
class Parent
{
    // T is incomplete here.
public:
    ~Parent() noexcept
    {
       // T is complete here.
       static_assert(std::is_base_of<Parent<T>, T>::value);
    }
public:
    T* next;
};
```